# Can the data on corrupt XFS disk be saved?

Tags: data-recovery, xfs

I have 6 SSD disks (`Disk model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 2TB`) equipped on a Linux server (`Rocky Linux 9.1`). Two m.2 to pcie converter cards are used, one holds 4 disks and the other holds 2. All disks were formatted into XFS and mounted as individual disks (no raid at all). They ran well until a system reboot. After that, all disks failed to be mounted and show same errors:

```
[   76.534528] XFS (nvme0n1): Mounting V5 Filesystem
[   76.535327] XFS (nvme0n1): totally zeroed log
[   76.535859] XFS (nvme0n1): Corruption warning: Metadata has LSN (1:23691) ahead of current LSN (1:0). Please unmount and run xfs_repair (>= v4.3) to resolve.
```

So I tried `xfs_repair` *without* `-L`, the results are

```
Sorry, could not find valid secondary superblock
Exiting now.
```

Can anyone give some hint if the data still be saved or not? If so, what should I try? I'm not a professional IT guy, hope the information are enough, but I'll be happy to provide more if you give instructions. Thanks!

--Ben

p.s. Also checked one of the disks with `smartctl`, the results are listed:

```shellsession
root@trump:~# smartctl -d nvme -r nvmeioctl -a /dev/nvme0n1
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-5.14.0-162.6.1.el9_1.0.1.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

 [NVMe call: opcode=0x06, size=0x1000, nsid=0x00000000, cdw10=0x00000001]
  [Duration: 0.003s]
 [NVMe call succeeded: result=0x00000000]
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
 [NVMe call: opcode=0x06, size=0x1000, nsid=0x00000001, cdw10=0x00000000]
  [Duration: 0.001s]
 [NVMe call succeeded: result=0x00000000]
Model Number:                       Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 2TB
Serial Number:                      S4J4NJ0N807891L
Firmware Version:                   2B2QEXM7
PCI Vendor ID:                      0x144d
PCI Vendor Subsystem ID:            0x144d
IEEE OUI Identifier:                0x002538
Total NVM Capacity:                 2,000,398,934,016 [2.00 TB]
Unallocated NVM Capacity:           0
Controller ID:                      4
NVMe Version:                       1.3
Number of Namespaces:               1
Namespace 1 Size:                   2,000,398,934,016 [2.00 TB]
Namespace 1 Capacity:               2,000,398,934,016 [2.00 TB]
Namespace 1 Utilization:            1,815,698,178,048 [1.81 TB]
Namespace 1 Formatted LBA Size:     512
Namespace 1 IEEE EUI-64:            002538 5801429f37
Local Time is:                      Wed Jan 10 11:03:58 2024 CST
Firmware Updates (0x16):            3 Slots, no Reset required
Optional Admin Commands (0x0017):   Security Format Frmw_DL Self_Test
Optional NVM Commands (0x005f):     Comp Wr_Unc DS_Mngmt Wr_Zero Sav/Sel_Feat Timestmp
Log Page Attributes (0x03):         S/H_per_NS Cmd_Eff_Lg
Maximum Data Transfer Size:         512 Pages
Warning  Comp. Temp. Threshold:     85 Celsius
Critical Comp. Temp. Threshold:     85 Celsius
Namespace 1 Features (0x00):        -

Supported Power States
St Op     Max   Active     Idle   RL RT WL WT  Ent_Lat  Ex_Lat
 0 +     7.50W       -        -    0  0  0  0        0       0
 1 +     5.90W       -        -    1  1  1  1        0       0
 2 +     3.60W       -        -    2  2  2  2        0       0
 3 -   0.0700W       -        -    3  3  3  3      210    1200
 4 -   0.0050W       -        -    4  4  4  4     2000    8000

Supported LBA Sizes (NSID 0x1)
Id Fmt  Data  Metadt  Rel_Perf
 0 +     512       0         0

=== START OF SMART DATA SECTION ===
 [NVMe call: opcode=0x02, size=0x0200, nsid=0xffffffff, cdw10=0x007f0002]
  [Duration: 0.002s]
 [NVMe call succeeded: result=0x00000000]
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

SMART/Health Information (NVMe Log 0x02)
Critical Warning:                   0x00
Temperature:                        34 Celsius
Available Spare:                    100%
Available Spare Threshold:          10%
Percentage Used:                    1%
Data Units Read:                    101,770,136 [52.1 TB]
Data Units Written:                 114,820,441 [58.7 TB]
Host Read Commands:                 232,483,188
Host Write Commands:                97,462,970
Controller Busy Time:               672
Power Cycles:                       73
Power On Hours:                     7,214
Unsafe Shutdowns:                   22
Media and Data Integrity Errors:    0
Error Information Log Entries:      77
Warning  Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Critical Comp. Temperature Time:    0
Temperature Sensor 1:               34 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 2:               34 Celsius
Temperature Sensor 3:               -
Temperature Sensor 4:               -
Temperature Sensor 5:               -
Temperature Sensor 6:               -
Temperature Sensor 7:               -
Temperature Sensor 8:               -
Thermal Temp. 1 Transition Count:   0
Thermal Temp. 2 Transition Count:   0
Thermal Temp. 1 Total Time:         0
Thermal Temp. 2 Total Time:         0

 [NVMe call: opcode=0x02, size=0x0400, nsid=0xffffffff, cdw10=0x00ff0001]
  [Duration: 0.002s]
 [NVMe call succeeded: result=0x00000000]
Error Information (NVMe Log 0x01, 16 of 64 entries)
Num   ErrCount  SQId   CmdId  Status  PELoc          LBA  NSID    VS
  0         77     0  0x0019  0x4004      -            0     0     -
```

Comment: check out https://www.reclaime.com/library/xfs-recovery.aspx; upside it is free to try and see what it proposes for a recovery; downside it's windows software and the license to do XFS is $190.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I can't comment yet...but this is important enough, I figure.

This program `photorec` saved my life once.

https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec
https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download
https://www.cgsecurity.org/testdisk.pdf

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information. From the document, I don't see if it can work with XFS file system. Also, my files on the disks are pure binary data collected from some experiment device. They are not photo, word, or other regular file types... Anyway, I'll give it a try. Thanks again.

Comment: @BenLau I thought the same thing. Photo's? Sure enough, 60 hours later (usb 2.0), scanning every block of a microsd 512gb, and that program recovered all 26gb of a web directory with every kind of file you could imagine.  It didn't recover the .zim files that were in the GB, 12.8gb wiki, 3gb askubuntu zim... the GB files didn't recover, but they were simple enough to get back, thankfully.